# class() takes no argumentes, can someone help me whit this

Tags: python, constructor

i cant find a way to make this work, the code won't run no matter what
the problem can be the varible dificuldade, or it can be the class Calcular

```
class Calcular:

    def __int__(self: object, dificuldade: int) -> None:
        self._dificuldade: int = dificuldade
        self._valor1: int = self._gerarValor
        self._valor2: int = self._gerarValor
        self._operacao: int = randint(1, 3)
        self._resultado: float = self.gerarResultado

    @property
    def dificuldade(self: object) -> int:
        return self._dificuldade

    @property
    def valor1(self: object) -> int:
         return self._valor1

    @property
    def valor2(self: object) -> int:
        return self._valor2

    @property
    def operacao(self: object) -> int:
        return self._operacao

    @property
    def resultado(self: object) -> int:
        return self._resultado

    def __str__(self: object) -> str:
        op: str = ''
        if self.operacao == 1:
            op = 'somar'

        elif self.operacao == 2:
            op= 'diminuir'

        elif self.operacao == 3:
            op= 'multiplicar'

        else:
            op= 'operação desconhecida'
        return f'valor1: {self.valor1} \nValor2: {self.valor2} \nDificuldade: {self.dificuldade} \nOperação: {op}'

    @property
    def _gerarValor(self) -> int:
        pass

    @property
    def _gerarResultado(self) -> int:
        pass

    def checarResultado(self, resposta: int) -> bool:
        pass

    def mostarOperacao(self) -> None:
        pass
```

and when i try to run it like this:

```
from models.calcular import Calcular

calc: Calcular = Calcular(dificuldade = 1)

print(Calcucar)
```

It displays this mesage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leonardoquintao/PycharmProjects/GAME/teste.py", line 3, in <module>
    calc: Calcular = Calcular(dificuldade = 1)
TypeError: Calcular() takes no arguments
```

Comment: typo. `__int__` should be `__init__`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. My general advice to you as a programmer is to *pay more attention to detail*. This is a common typo, but also I had to fix the [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for your post.